# SpringBoot Transaction Isolation Level

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, transactions, spring-data-jpa

I'm having this project trying to check transaction isolation. I started with READ_UNCOMMITTED level and it doesn't work.
The code is pretty simple.

The main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateTransactionsLocksTestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HibernateTransactionsLocksTestApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

The controller

```
    @RestController
    public class HomeController {

        private final AccountService accountService;

        public HomeController(AccountService accountService) {
            this.accountService = accountService;
        }

        @GetMapping("/updateAccount2RU")
        public String updateAccount2RU() throws InterruptedException {
            accountService.updateAccount2RU();
            return "done!";
        }

        @GetMapping("/update2Account2RU")
        public String update2Account2RU() throws InterruptedException {
            accountService.update2Account2RU();
            return "done!";
        }
}
```

The Service

```
@Service
public class AccountService {

    private final AccountRepository accountRepository;

    public AccountService(AccountRepository accountRepository) {
        this.accountRepository = accountRepository;
    }

    @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)
    public void updateAccount2RU() throws InterruptedException {
        Account a = accountRepository.findById(2).get();
        System.out.println("Account amount: " + a.getAmount());
        a.setAmount(a.getAmount()+1);
        accountRepository.save(a);
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(5000);
    }

    @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)
    public void update2Account2RU() throws InterruptedException {
        Account a = accountRepository.findById(2).get();
        System.out.println("Account amount: " + a.getAmount());
        a.setAmount(a.getAmount()+1);
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(5000);
    }

}
```

Repository is a simple SpringData repository

```
@Repository
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, Integer> {

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY, isolation = Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)
    Account findByName(String name);
}
```

application.properties

```
server.contextPath=/

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/trasactions-locks-tests
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect =org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE

spring.jpa.open-in-view=false

#Check transactions behaviour
logging.level.org.springframework.transaction.interceptor=TRACE
```

Basically I open 2 tabs in Chrome and access updateAccount2RU (this should read the account and increment the amount and the thread should sleep for 5 seconds before waking up and commiting the transaction) and in the meantime I access the second method update2Account2RU which reads the same account and the amount is the same read from the first method, not the updated one.

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely need to use `accountRepository.save(a);` in the first method.

SQL updates are typically buffered by Hibernate until such time as the transaction is committed i.e. when your transactional method returns.

There are therefore no pending uncommitted database changes at the point when T2 reads the record.

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)
public void updateAccount2RU() throws InterruptedException {
    Account a = accountRepository.findById(2).get();
    System.out.println("Account amount: " + a.getAmount());
    a.setAmount(a.getAmount()+1);

    // force explicit flush so T2 should now see the uncommitted change
    accountRepository.saveAndFlush(a);

    Thread.currentThread().sleep(5000);
}
```

See:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/objectstate-flushing.html

> From time to time the Session will execute the SQL statements needed
>   to synchronize the JDBC connection's state with the state of objects
>   held in memory. This process, flush, occurs by default at the
>   following points
>
> - before some query executions
> - from org.hibernate.Transaction.commit()
> - from Session.flush()

Comment: isn't saveAndFlush actually comitting so that when the second method is executed, it reads an commited row(meaning there's no difference between READ_UNCOMITTED and READ_COMITTED)? 
I checked and with saveAndFlush both READ_UNCOMITTED and READ_COMITTED see the change

Comment: No, it isn't. Commit/Rollback still happens when the method returns.

Comment: Then why the second method reads the updated value even with READ_COMITTED?

Comment: I think your original question has been answered. You should accept and ask a new question for further issues. I can gurantee 100% flush != commit.